# Soft-coding values to a yaml file for loaddata option

Tags: django, yaml, django-fixtures

I have the following model:

```
class Plan(TimeStampedModel):   
    name = models.CharField(_("Plan name"), max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

The `TimeStampedModel` it inherits from has created and changed dates:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """Reusable template to add created/last updated timestamps to a model"""

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
    changed_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Last changed"), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now I run a `loaddata` from yaml files looking like this:

```
- model: plans.Plan
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: Basic plan
```

This gives me an error because the load complains that I haven't defined the timestamp data.

What I would like to do, rather than just setting a default timestamp (which I can if it becomes necessary), is just pass the current timestamp for the date/time I am running `loaddata`, which will then get applied to all the yaml files.

Running `python manage.py testserver demo_data/fixtures/plans.yaml` bypasses the DB constraints, and the `auto_now` options as far as I can see, so the way these fields would normally be set isn't applied.

Is there a way of doing this? I can't find anything, not even a similar question, in my searches.

Comment: I just discovered node anchors in yaml, but even setting hard coded values there and inheriting them under the "fields" doesn't seem to work - I guess django doesn't support them and it's just a "basic" format?